# Determine bias of estimator?

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator

If I have a unbiased estimator, I may obtain another estimator through a reparametrisation. Say, if I have $\lambda$ for a sequences of iid exponentials, I have the unbiased estimator $\sum X/n$, and if I want an estimate for $\exp(- \lambda)$, I can use the estimator $\exp( - \sum X/n)$.

My question is, how do I determine the bias of such estimators? I don't need the actual mean of the estimator, I just want to confirm if there is a bias or not.

Comment: Whether or not an estimator is biased is determined by statistical theory (derivations from first principles). Do you mean that you want to know if *your sample estimate* is biased?

Comment: Do you know the distribution of $\bar{X}_n$?

Comment: As soon as you transform an unbiased estimator by a non-linear function, you obtain a biased estimator of the transform. Except a few exotic exceptions of less than considerable interest.

Comment: This looks like routine book-work as might be set for a course; it should probably have a `self-study` [tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you know that $\hat{\lambda}=\bar{X}$ is unbiased for $\lambda$.

Note that $\exp(-x)$ is convex, so you should be able to see how to apply [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality); and given $\text{Var}(X)$ is not zero, you should be able to argue that the inequality is strict (i.e. that the equality case in Jensen's inequality won't occur)